# Behavior of a pin that, initially is configured as output, but, inevitably is configured as input when it should not be

Tags: electrical

Helo, all !!

I have a doubt, I'm using a MC9S12DP512 microcontroller to read another microcontroller, that I will name it as A. But I'm having some problems. Here, I will present you a image of a log made with an oscilloscope. The Blue signal, I will name it X, and the Red I will name it Y.
So, The X pin( the blue signal) needs to be an output, and the Y pin(The red signal) Needs to be an input. However, both pins are at the same port, Port H, on the MC9S12DP512 microcontroller. And, the driver that I'm using, change the direction of all pins of the Port H at the same time.
[image]
[image]

So, I observed that, after the command below, The X (Blue signal) goes to low-logic.

DDRH = 0x00;   / DDRH is Port H Data Direction Register */

I observed too that,the Y (Red signal) seems to be very attenuated in some instants and others moments don't.

I did the same test, using the same microcontroller MC9S12DP512 to read anothers similar devices on the other side, all others similar devices has the same internal microcontroller, that I called it as A, and the majority were read without problems, and the pulses did not appear. Only one of them showed problems. I know that the problem is not in this particular device, because it can be read by others equipements that I have and it works fine.

So, I have two doubts.

1. Why signal X(The Blue one) has the behavior showed on the figure ?
2. Why this behavior does not happen when I do it using a MC9S12DP512 to read a similar device with the same microcontroller A on the other side?

Thank you very much!

Added Later:

Both microcontroller are 5V. By the read line I expect to read the microcontroller A using the MC9S12DP512. By the blue Line I expect to write to microcontroller A using the MC9S12DP512. But, the reading and writting does no happen at the same time. 
It is part of a JTAG communication, the red is TDO and Blue is RST

Comment: I'm having trouble getting past your statement, "And, the driver that I'm using, change the direction of all pins of the Port H at the same time" . . .   If you need inputs AND outputs on Port H and the driver doesn't let you do it, just how are you planning to succeed?

Comment: That red signal looks like it has contention (i.e. multiple drivers.. both devices driving?).. until, at some point later, it doesn't (or overcomes it).. and then, does again :/  Try to _detail_ the differences, if any, between the two setups.

Comment: Why can't red line be driven by A?? What are the voltage levels both are operating at

Comment: I don't designed the code, but the signals does not work at the same time. When I'm reading the writing is not important and vice-versa. The intriguing is that this code works with a similar device, with the same microcontroller A. So, Why it works with a microcontroller A, with the same connections and everything, and not with the other ?

Comment: Why is every fourth blue pulse is higher than others? What signal it is? Data, clock or

Comment: @Umar I edited and added the adticional information at the end of the post. The signal is a JTAG signal. TDO line is red and RST line is blue

Comment: Are you trying to emulate JTAG using the MC9S12MCU? You should have told this in the beginning. I believe, as long as you don't tell what A is, you will be fine. 

Comment: Can you try isolating red line and measure TDO again? Do you have any series resistor in the trace?? May be also disconnect blue line from A if possible and measure again

Comment: @Umar , Yes, I'm trying to emulate a jtag, sorry for did not say at he begining.But, how to isolate TDO? It is alread isolated T. It has not series resistor, at least by my side of the hardware( the side with the MC9S12MCU )

Comment: Are both MCUs are on same boards?

Comment: @Umar, no they are in different boards

Comment: If you disconnect the Board with MCU A and measure the TDO of MC9S MCU, how does the line look?

Comment: @Umar I will try it. I will disconnect the board with the microcontroller A and measure the TDO and RST of the MC9S

Comment: @Umar Sorry for the delayed answer. But , There was no signal at TDO when I measured the TDO of MC9S after disconnect the board with MCU A

Comment: @Umar I discover my problem. The problem is that, In my hardware, I have a SN74ABT16245A in the middle. It is like a switch that can enable and control the direction of the pins. But, I can only control the direction of a entire port, not only pins.

Comment: @Daniel good news!! Why was the problem only in one board?

Comment: @Umar I don't know yet. At the beginning I can read  the ID code of microcontroller A via JTAG, but, I don't know why, when I will try to read the memory this problem that I related here, happens, and happens only in one board. I need to investigate a bit more

Comment: @Umar Good news, the problem was solved. I rewrite the code to read the TDO pin and it worked. I was affraid to damage the chip. The risk really exists, but, it was the only way... I maintained the direction of the pins and altered the direction of the SN74ABT16245A port, just to read and, after read it, I returned it to the state that is less susceptible to damage. During the reading, I have the output of SN74ABT16245A  connected with the output of my microcontroller, and I think it is no good, but I do it for a very short time

Comment: @Daniel Place a 100 ohm resistor in series if possible..if it doesn't affect your speed

Comment: @Umar Where do you advise to put this resistor ?

Comment: between the buffer and the external IC.. so that even if there is a short accidentally for short moment, current will be limited.